# Facing issue in setting message body in MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: ios, swift, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller, arabic-support

I am trying to set message body as "567" in `MFMessageComposeViewController`. But the text in the body is hiding behind the send button. I am using Arabic as the default language in a device (OS 12.1). If anyone faced same issue kindly help me with it.[image]

Here is the screenshot attached below.

Comment: You need to localize your app for Arabic.